# netcat not sending LAST_ACK

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, client-server, netcat

I have this script that sends packages to a server written with *boost::asio*, listening on x.x.x.x:yyyyy. Every 1-2 seconds it stops for another 2-10 seconds then starts again and sends. During the pause the server is in FIN_WAIT2 and client in CLOSE_WAIT. The server reports no received packages during the pause and doesn't hang or something.

*script.bash:*

```
#!/bin/bash

x0=$(< "request0.txt")
x1=$(< "request1.txt")
x2=$(< "request2.txt")
x3=$(< "request3.txt")
while true ;
do
num=$(( $RANDOM % 4 ))
var="x$num"
echo "${!var}" | nc x.x.x.x yyyyy
done
```

*watch -n1 "netstat -anlp | grep yyyyy":*

```
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:yyyyy       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      43810/server
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:17544       x.x.x.x:yyyyy       FIN_WAIT2   222862/nc
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:yyyyy       x.x.x.x:17544       CLOSE_WAIT  43810/server
```

What does this mean? is netcat not sending LAST_ACK? Why? Am I interpreting this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> netcat not sending LAST_ACK

Processes don't 'send `LAST_ACK.`' `LAST_ACK` is a *state* of a *port,* not a message.

> During the pause the server is in FIN_WAIT2 and client in CLOSE_WAIT.

No. You have this back to front. The server is listening on the local port `yyyy`, and it is `yyyy` that is in `CLOSE_WAIT`. This means that TCP is waiting for the local process to close the socket: in this case, the *server.* The client has connected via local port 17544, and it is *this* port which is in `FIN_WAIT_2.`

Conclusion: your server isn't closing the accepted socket when it reads end-of-stream.